# How does "dual-line" feature work on Cisco/Avaya IP phones for VOIP?

Tags: voip, cisco-voip, avaya

For below CME configuration which I configured on UC500 where ephones are not configured with dual-line feature and in button command separator 'c'(call waiting) is used.

```
CME_VOICE(config)#ephone-dn 10
CME_VOICE(config-ephone-dn)#number 1010
CME_VOICE(config-ephone-dn)#no huntstop

CME_VOICE(config)#ephone-dn 11
CME_VOICE(config-ephone-dn)#number 1010
CME_VOICE(config-ephone-dn)#preference 1
CME_VOICE(config-ephone-dn)#no huntstop

CME_VOICE(config)#ephone 8
CME_VOICE(config-ephone)#button 1c10,11

CME_VOICE(config)#ephone 9
CME_VOICE(config-ephone)#button 1c10,11
```

what will happen if a guy is already busy on ephone 8 and at the same time second call to '1010' comes in? Would call ring on ephone 8? If YES, then please explain why? In my opinion since I haven't configured ephone with dual-line feature, receiving second call on that ephone is not possible even when we have configured it for call waiting. Another question is what will happen for below configuration:

```
CME_VOICE(config)#ephone-dn 10 dual-line
CME_VOICE(config-ephone-dn)#number 1010
CME_VOICE(config-ephone-dn)#no huntstop

CME_VOICE(config)#ephone-dn 11 dual-line
CME_VOICE(config-ephone-dn)#number 1010
CME_VOICE(config-ephone-dn)#preference 1
CME_VOICE(config-ephone-dn)#no huntstop

CME_VOICE(config)#ephone 8
CME_VOICE(config-ephone)#button 1o10,11

CME_VOICE(config)#ephone 9
CME_VOICE(config-ephone)#button 1o10,11
```

Comment: You might have better luck on Serverfault.  Application questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

If the huntstop attribute is set, an incoming call does not roll over (hunt) to another ephone-dn when the called ephone-dn is busy or does not answer and a hunting strategy has been established that includes this ephone-dn.

When the no huntstop command is used on the ephone-dn, the call would ring on the first ephone-dn and go through any hunting defined on the two channels in a dual-line ephone-dn before being sent to the next most preferred ephone-dn that also has a matching destination pattern. This will continue until an ephone-dn with huntstop configured is reached or no more dial peers (ephone-dns) have matching destinations patterns.

The difference in configuration between overlaid ephone-dns with call waiting and overlaid ephone-dns without call waiting is that overlaid ephone-dns with call waiting use the **c** keyword in the button command and overlaid ephone-dns without call waiting use the **o** keyword.

Call waiting allows phone users to know that another person is calling them while they are talking on the phone. Phone users hear a call-waiting tone indicating that another party is trying to reach them. Calls to IP phones with soft keys can be answered with the Answer soft key.

Example-

A Cisco Unified IP Phone 7910 (maximum two call-waiting calls) has a button configured with a set of overlaid ephone-dns with call waiting (button 1c1,2,3,4). A call to ephone-dn 1 is answered. A call to ephone-dn 2 generates call-waiting notification. Calls to ephone-dn 3 and ephone-dn 4 will wait in line and remain invisible to the phone user until one of the two original calls ends. When the call to ephone-dn 1 ends, the phone user can then talk to the person who called ephone-dn 2. The call to ephone-dn 3 issues call-waiting notification while the call to ephone-dn 4 waits in line

The following example demonstrates call waiting for overlaid ephone-dns that are
shared on two phones:

ephone 1

button 1c1,2,3,4

!

ephone 2

button 1c1,2,3,4

1. A call to ephone-dn 1 rings on ephone 1 and on ephone 2. Ephone 1 answers, and the call is no longer visible to ephone 2.
2. A call to ephone-dn 2 issues a call-waiting notification to ephone 1 and rings on ephone 2, which answers. The second call is no longer visible to ephone 1.
3. A call to ephone-dn 3 issues a call-waiting notification to ephone 1 and ephone 2. Ephone 1 puts the call to ephone-dn 1 on hold and answers the call to ephone-dn 3. The call to ephone-dn 3 is no longer visible to ephone 2.
4. A call to ephone-dn 4 is issues a call-waiting notification on ephone 2. The call is not visible on ephone 1 because it has met the two-call maximum by handling the calls to ephone-dn 1 and ephone-dn 3. (Note that the call maximum is six for those phones that are able to handle six call-waiting calls, as previously described.)

There are a few more differences between seperator **o** and **c**.
For further explanation you can check [SRND](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/cucme/admin/configuration/guide/cmeadm.pdf) for CME. If there is still some confusion, please leave a comment. I can explain it to you.